# Differences between "stupid to the last drop" and "stupid"

Tags: phrases, differences, meaning-in-context

My colleague was screaming *You are stupid to the last drop* at another colleague who accidentally formatted her hard disk.

Is there such an expression as *stupid to the last drop*? Are there differences between *stupid to the last drop* and *stupid*?

Comment: I suggest 'stupid as a bag of hair/hammers/rocks'. These are all well-received expressions meaning "dumber'n just plain stupid". 'stupid to the last drop' is just being clever and is not an idiom.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Maxwell House](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_House), a well-known if not well-respected brand of coffee in the US, has (had?) a famous slogan that eventually entered the wider lexicon: *Good to the last drop.*

While that phrase can be heard in various contexts, I've rarely if ever heard the adjective *good* swapped out for another, nor am I familiar with the phrase being used without any liquid reference point. (That's not to say that the liquid in question is always coffee -- plenty of oral sex jokes also make use of the slogan.)

Your colleague was intending to humorously intensify the adjective by saying *to the last drop*, but I wouldn't call that standard usage.

Comment: Oh I see, so my colleague was `humorously angrily shouting` at my other colleague for formatting her hard disk. - That's interesting +1

Comment: OMG, I've been drinking coffee of ill repute!  :-)

Comment: @DeepYellow I'm a Nescafe addict myself; I don't speak as a coffee snob, but rather as someone who's been scolded by coffee snobs. ^_^

Comment: Not unlike the phrase, "from zero to stupid in 60 words." Taking a common trope and interposing pejoratives to play off established cultural memes is an emergent genre.

Comment: +1 for onomatomaniak - I like your sentence `scolded by coffee snobs. ^_^`

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy to guess what is the difference- to the last drop put a stress on the durability and means like stubbornly doing something stupid all over again.

Aka
 People are polluting nature but they are being stupid to the last drop.

Comment: +1 Nice one - `put a stress on the durability and means like stubbornly doing something stupid all over again.` I was wondering if my colleague would say next time, probably `stupid to the core`??